# Can I directly plant a cut-off Dracaena trifasciata?

Tags: planting, roots, dracaena

My wife is apparently planning to expand our apartment garden with [Dracaena trifasciata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_trifasciata). Right now it is standing in a bit of water (to get some roots I guess).

[image]

It is however unfortunately more lying than standing because of me, the cat, the window etc.

**My question**: is it possible to directly plant it in soil without waiting for the small roots to sprout? <sup>note</sup>

This is how the bottom part looks today

[image]

---

<sub><sup>note</sup> This should considerably improve its chances of making it to Christmas. I do no want to ask my wife because she is not around and I will take the opportunity of her stay with friends to plant it and call it a day (and assume the consequences, but with competent information in this post. This means that it will be your fault)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I grow variations of the snake plant, calling them all Sansevaria.
   They all reliably **root directly in soil (99%)**. Sansevaria Moonshine has greyish green leaves under a foot high (good for the office):

   [image: Sansevaria Moonshine]
2. As they grow at the foot of rainforests I've visited, a moist and fertile medium is called for.
3. Troopers, they will bloom if you give them a South window - honeysuckle scent. But they also will live if not thrive in a closet, watered once a month, no exaggeration. I let them dry between waterings to stimulate the plant's need to root.
4. When friends say they have a black thumb, they get a snake plant and find it's getting greener.